# OPENCART APP -> Customer Orders not being bound to Customer

Tags: php, android, jquery, mobile, opencart

Customer Orders not being bound to Customer

Postby DrFeeling » Mon Jun 01, 2015 4:05 pm
Good Afternoon peeps, I'm currently developping a mobile app for opencart that will bridge both tecnologies.

Most of the stuff is already active but I have a problem regarding order histories.

So, when you purchase something, through the main site, the default template of opencart, it generates a order history, that you can see through the website (my orders) or through the admin page.

My problem is that, whenever someone purchases something from the app, the orders of that costumer arent uptaded.
Though they appear in the main admin window (the dashboard) , once you go to customer (sales -> customers -> customers) the order made by the app isnt listed in the myOrders part of that customer, making both the "my previous orders" and the order of that customer inexistent in that place, but they appear in the dashboard and the notification email is foward to the customer

Please help me, and thanks for the support :D

Only order 261 (which was made in the website) is bounded to its customer, the others arent, as you can see in the pic below

AM I missing a parameter or a validation when the checkout process happens?

http://s16.postimg.org/y2h9rg5fp/image.jpg

EDIT: My code to create a order:
public function end_order() {

```
        if ($this->customer->isLogged() == true){
        $data= array();
        $datap = array();

        $this->load->model('account/customer');
        $this->load->model('quickcheckout/order');
        $this->load->model('checkout/order');

        $myArray = $_POST["formData"];
        $treatedArray = array();
        foreach($myArray as $value) {
                 $treatedArray[$value['name']] = $value['value'];
        }

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $delivery = $_POST["deladdress"];
        $delivery = array_shift($delivery); // sobe um nivel as posiçoes do array, em vez de usar $array[0]['bla'] , usasse so $array['bla']

        $data2 = array();
        $data2 = $this->model_account_customer->getCustomerByEmail($email);

        $Method = $_POST["PayMethod"];

        $TotalCheckout = $_POST["TotalCheck"];

        $IP = $_POST["IP"];
        $Agent = $_POST["User"];

        $Products = $_POST["Prod"];
        $length = count($Products);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          (int)$datap[$i]['product_id'] = $Products[$i]['Id'];
          $datap[$i]['name'] = $Products[$i]['Name'];
          $datap[$i]['model'] = $Products[$i]['modelo'];
          (int)$datap[$i]['quantity'] = $Products[$i]['NItems'];
          $datap[$i]['price'] = $Products[$i]['Preco'];
          $datap[$i]['total'] = $Products[$i]['Total'];
          $datap[$i]['tax'] =  0; //$Products[$i]['Tax'];
          (int)$datap[$i]['reward'] = 0; //$Products[$i]['Reward'];
        }

        $url = $myurl;

        $data['invoice_prefix'] = $this->config->get('config_invoice_prefix');
        $data['store_id'] = $this->config->get('config_store_id');
        $data['store_name'] = "Loja Teste";
        $data['store_url'] = $url;
        $data['firstname'] = $data2['firstname'] ;
        $data['lastname'] =  $data2['lastname'];
        $data['email'] = $data2['email'];
        $data['telephone'] = $data2['telephone'];
        $data['fax'] = $data2['fax'];
        $data['payment_firstname'] = $delivery['firstname'];
        $data['payment_lastname'] = $delivery['lastname'];
        $data['payment_company'] = $delivery['company'];
        $data['payment_company_id'] = $delivery['company_id'];;
        $data['tax_id'] = $delivery['tax_id'];
        $data['payment_address_1'] = $delivery['address_1'];
        $data['payment_address_2'] = $delivery['address_2'];
        $data['payment_city'] = $delivery['city'];
        $data['payment_postcode'] = $delivery['postcode']; 
        $data['payment_country'] = $delivery['country'];
        $data['payment_country_id'] = $delivery['country_id'];
        $data['payment_zone'] = $delivery['zone'];
        $data['payment_zone_id'] = $delivery['zone_id'];
        $data['payment_method'] = "Cash On Delivery";
        $data['payment_code'] = 1; 
        $data['total'] = $TotalCheckout;
        //NOTA: esta duas variaveis abaixo servem para tratar dos preços, alterar depois para quando a loja tiver opçoes de escolher preços
        $data['language_id'] = (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id');
        $data['accept_language'] = $this->request->server['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
        $data['currency_id'] = (int)2;
        $data['currency_code'] = "USD";
        $data['currency_value'] = (float)1.00000000;
        $data['ip'] = $IP;
        $data['forwarded_ip'] = $IP;
        $data['user_agent'] = $Agent;
        $data['products'] = $datap;

        (int)$order = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);

        $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order, 1 , $comment = '', $notify = false);

        echo ("teste");
        }


    }
```

Comment: make sure that when you add an order to the database you do it the same way OC does (class `ModelCheckoutOrder` @ function `addOrder` in the file `<OC_ROOT>/catalog/model/checkout/order.php`)

Comment: I'm using this code in my php link from my mobile app to the web aplication, the order is created with no problems , only the history is not being created: (int)$order = $this->model_checkout_order->addOrder($data);

   $this->model_checkout_order->confirm($order, 1 , $comment = '', $notify = false);